# On tags for technical support

Tags: discussion, tags

I doubt that tags like [installation](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/installation) is of any use. No one is probably going to watch or use this tag, because people don't tend to learn everything about the installation of every proof assistant.

I suggest merging all the tags into [technical-support](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-support). It should concern things like software installation and settings, and peripheral tooling. This way, people can filter out these contents systematically if they don't want to see these.

Comment: I would feel more inclined towards this change if there was more than one tag fitting in this category

Comment: Yes, a list of said tags to be merged to that tag, and the number of occurrences, would improve this FR.

Comment: Who would follow "technical-support" if they would not follow "installation"?